# Bash - compare two files and extract the line numbers where lines are identical

Tags: bash, awk

I have two files:

File1:

```
water
doggy
moors
```

File2:

```
water1234
forge4432
moors5432
```

I need to compare the first 5 characters in each line in `File2` with the characters in each line in `File1`, in order to find out which lines in `File1` are identical to the same lines in `File2`

So, to illustrate, `water` and `moors` are shared by both `File1` and `File2`, so my expected output should be:

```
1
3
```

Meaning line 1 and line 3 are shared by both files.

This is my attempt using `awk`, but it does not work:

```
awk '/substr($1,1,5)/{ print NR; exit }' File2 File1
```

My logic was to extract the first 5 characters of ever line in `File2` and then print the line where it exists in `File1`.

For this question, it is assumed that every line in `File1` is 5 characters long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approachi of using `substr` in awk seems the way for this. Note, though, thath you have to "play" with `FNR` and `NR` and also store the values for a further comparison:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=substr($0,0,5); next} a[FNR]==$1 {print FNR}' f2 f1
1
3
```

#### Explanation

This reads the file2 and then file1. When reading the first, it stores the 5 first characters into the array `a[]` using the line number as index. Then, it keeps comparing these values with the second file and printing the line when it matches.

- `FNR==NR {}` when reading the first file, do `{}`.
- In this case, `{a[NR]=substr($0,0,5); next}`: get the 5 first characters and store in the `a[]` array. Then, move to the next line.
- `a[FNR]==$1 {print FNR}` when reading the second file, compare the value of the line with what was stored in the array `a[]` for this line number. If it matches, print the line number.

Answer (score 1):

```
sort <(cat -n <(cut -b 1-5 file1)) <(cat -n <(cut -b 1-5 file2)) | uniq -d | cut -b 1-6
```

Output:

```
     1
     3
```